# Updating style of HTML button using Javascript (Jquery Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this button below

```
<button class="small_button" id="chicken_button" data-icon="" onclick="smallButtonClicked(this.id)">Chicken</button>
```

When the button is clicked it calls a function, that among other things is meant to add a check to the button

```
function smallButtonClicked(id){
  var button = document.querySelector(".small_button#" + id);
  var x = button.getAttribute("data-icon");
  if (x == "check"){
    console.log("remove")
    button.setAttribute("data-icon", "");
  }
  else{
    console.log("add")
    button.setAttribute("data-icon", "check");
  }
}
```

However, despite this updating the HTML, the button does not change on the screen. I have tried using the below method suggested on the Jquery website but it returns the following error "Cannot call methods prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

```
$(".small_button#chicken_button").button("refresh")
```

Anyone have any ideas how to refresh my custom button? I don't want to use the standard Jquery button.

Comment: Your use of `refresh` is correct, you just need to do it within a document.ready event handler.

Comment: Even with the document ready handler it still returns the same initialisation error

Comment: Could you show a sample of the issue in a http://jsfiddle.net? It's hard to see what you're doing exactly. Are there any errors in the console? Also, it's a little odd that you're using native JS methods along with jQuery

Comment: Here you go.. https://jsfiddle.net/h9m5L6gu/ I'm new to this whole Jquery thing, it's part of a PhoneGap project at uni and this is the first time I've used it.

Answer (score 0):

data-icon attribute is for li tag
if you want to use it with button how about try this

your button

```
<button class="small_button ui-btn" id="chicken_button" onclick="smallButtonClicked(this.id)">Chicken</button>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function smallButtonClicked(id){
  var button = document.querySelector("#" + id);
  var x = button.getAttribute("class");
  if (x == "small_button ui-btn ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-right"){
    console.log("remove")
    button.setAttribute("class", "small_button ui-btn");
  }
  else{
    console.log("add")
    button.setAttribute("class", "small_button ui-btn ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-right");
  }
}
</script>
```

but if you want to use li then

your ui li

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">    
  <li data-icon=""><a id="chicken_button" href="javascript:void(0);" id="chicken_button" onclick="smallButtonClicked(this.id)" class="ui-btn">Chicken</a></li>
</ul>
```

this js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function smallButtonClicked(id){

  var x = $( "#"+id ).parent().attr("data-icon");

  if (x == "check"){
    console.log("remove")
    $( "#"+id ).attr("class", "ui-btn");
    $( "#"+id ).parent().attr("data-icon", "");
  }
  else{
    console.log("add")
    $( "#"+id ).attr("class", "ui-btn ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-right");
    $( "#"+id ).parent().attr("data-icon","check");
  }

}
</script>
```

or use this js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function smallButtonClicked(id){

  var x = $( "#"+id ).attr("class");;

  if (x == "ui-btn ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-right"){
    console.log("remove")
    $( "#"+id ).attr("class", "ui-btn");
  }
  else{
    console.log("add")
    $( "#"+id ).attr("class", "ui-btn ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-right");
  }

}
</script>
```

Hope it helps